# What if lseek() pass beyond the beginning of the file?

Tags: c, linux, lseek

As the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek) highlighted, the `lseek()` function allows the file offset to be set beyond the end of the file. But what if I set it beyond the beginning of the file?

Let the current offset be 5, What will actually happen when I try `lseek(fd, 10, SEEK_END)` ?

As mentioned, assume that I create a new file, and call the function `write(fd, buf, 5)` . The current file offset would be 5. Then using lseek function above, I expect the result would either be 0 or some errors may occurred.

Comment: That sounds like something that'd be awfully easy to just try.

Comment: I still appreciate it. Actually I tried it and know this question doesn't have practical uses. I just want to clarify my understanding of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you're asking if you can seek to before the beginning of the file (which your code example wouldn't do):

The [specification for lseek()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html) says that it will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINVAL`:

> The whence argument is not a proper value, or the resulting file offset would be negative for a regular file, block special file, or directory.